# Thread synchronization with Task.ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Consider the following code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class MyClass
{
    private int count;

    public async Task<int> MyReadAsync(Stream stream, byte[] buffer)
    {
        var read = await
            stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
        this.count += read;
        return read;
    }
}
```

Let's assume that this `MyReadAsync` method is directly called from an event handler of a WPF application, as follows:

```
private async void OnWhatever(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await myObject.MyReadAsync(this.stream, this.buffer);
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` allows that the portion of the code that starts with the line `this.count += read;` can be executed on any threadpool thread, correct?
2. For two separate calls of `MyReadAsync`, there is no guarantee that the portion of the code that starts with `this.count += read;` will be executed on the same thread, correct?
3. If 1 & 2 are correct, then it seems to me that the code `this.count += read;` should be protected with appropriate thread synchronization primitives, correct?

Comment: I think a question you should ask first is: do `Stream`s even support starting a new read while another one is still in progress? Does doing that even make sense?

Comment: @svick: Even if the Stream does not start the second read until the first one is finished, there would still be a race condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. To avoid any thread synchronization issues you should apply appropriate locking around the line that is incrementing the count

Comment: Thanks, as far as I have seen nobody has so far bothered to mention that the use of ConfigureAwait(false) might make thread synchronization necessary. I would think this is not immediately obvious to everybody and could therefore lead to many hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: in this case Interlocked rather than lock

Comment: Yup, Interlocked would be sufficient.